# How to store paid and unpaid orders in database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

I'm designing a database where I need to store **paid orders** and **unpaid orders** of a **customer.** Both categories of orders have **same attributes and relationships** with other tables.

I have come up with two designs:

**1. Separate tables for the two categories of orders:**[image]**Pros:** This design helps me to quickly differentiate between the orders in cart and those which are paid. Whenever a customer revisits my website, I just need to lookup the UnpaidOrder table for that particular customer and my cart is ready.

**Cons:** Whenever the payment for an order in UnpaidOrder table is made, I need to move the corresponding rows (of UnpaidOrder and other tables linked with it) to PaidOrder table and its corresponding tables. Also this design will require 2x number of tables: eg. UnpaidOrderDeliveryAddress, UnpaidOrderCreditCard, ... for relationships with UnpaidOrder and PaidOrderDeliveryAddress, PaidOrderCreditCard, ... for PaidOrder.

**2. Common table for both categories and an extra Status attribute:**[image]**Pros:** I don't need to move multiple rows on payment of an unpaid order. Also, the number of tables for corresponding relationships is halved.

**Cons:** I'm storing an extra Status attribute for each row. Whenever a customer revisits my website, I need to lookup the Order table and I need to check the Status attribute (paid/unpaid) of each row for that particular customer. As a result, the cart will take a longer time to load.

---

**My questions are:**

- Which is the better design in terms of performance, keeping in mind that there are numerous users and it is a heavy application?
- Are there any good alternatives for my requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another Opinion....

There is no need for extra normalization tables (UnpaidOrderDeliveryAddress, UnpaidOrderCreditCard, ... for relationships with UnpaidOrder and PaidOrderDeliveryAddress, PaidOrderCreditCard, ... for PaidOrder).  If you argue that `FOREIGN KEYs` need such, I will argue against using `FOREIGN KEYs` in such situations.  Simple indexes will suffice.

Since you will eventually have far more "paid" entries than "unpaid" entries, and paid entries are essentially 'history' that you rarely need to touch, I lean toward 2 tables.

I probably would not use a Trigger -- I would rather do it in application code where I have more control.

Are you expecting more than 100 SQL statements per second to be executed?  If not, I would not call it "heavy".

Be sure to carefully surround appropriate groups of statements with `BEGIN..COMMIT`.  Also, use `FOR UPDATE` on SELECTs that are leading to UPDATEs.

Comment: by simple indexes, do you mean that I need to use a common key for the tables (PaidOrder/UnpaidOrder has 1 to 0..1 relationship with PaidOrder____/UnpaidOrder____ tables). If I use a common key, how will I map a particular record in OrderCreditCard (since you said I don't need extra normalization tables) with PaidOrder/UnpaidOrder tables. A particular key (if common) in OrderCreditCard, say '111' may map to both PaidOrder/UnpaidOrder. In other words, if I'm using a common key and I want it to work, no two primary keys in PaidOrder and UnpaidOrder can be same.

Comment: Also, don't you think moving "paid" records from "unpaid" table to "paid" table is a clumsy approach? PS: I'm new to database designing.

Comment: An ORDER is an ORDER, whether it is paid or not.  When you create an order, give it a unique order_id and put `order_id` in other table(s) as needed.  Ditto for credit cards, etc.  An Order starts out in `UnpaidOrders` and is given an `order_id` (perhaps via `AUTO_INCREMENT`).  When it is moved to `PaidOrders`, it keeps the same `order_id`, but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Comment: If you ask my opinion, I like this answer better than mine.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand. I won't require extra tables if I designed in this way by making `PaidOrder` not `AUTO_INCREMENT`. I have one concern though. Is it a good practice to move records from one table to another in this fashion?

Comment: Moving records from one table to another is "clumsy" and probably not good practice.  The alternative is a table with lots of rows you are usually ignoring, plus building compound indexes that include `status`.  Neither approach is great.  Another question:  Do you really need to filter on `status` that often??  If not often, then my suggestion is bad and you should have a single set of tables.

Comment: Filter on `status` has to be performed every time a user visits my website in order to load the cart. So you can say that it has to be performed considerable number of times. Considering this as an ecommerce application, what will be your final verdict?

Comment: If you are filtering on both `status` and `user_id`, do you have a 'compound index'?   Or is `user_id` the PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: `user_id` is the primary key. I haven't added a `compound index` as of now. But I don't mind adding it if there's a need.

Comment: `status` is in the `Orders` table?  Customer to Orders is 1:many?  What are the keys in `Orders`?

Comment: Yes, `Status` would be in `Orders` table. `Customer` to `Order` is one:many. `Order_id` would be the `PRIMARY KEY` in `Order`.

Comment: `INDEX(Customer_id, Status)` is likely to be a good index into `Order` (in addition to the PK).

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned about performance, one possible suggestion is that you could do something like version 2, but with a trigger to run a separate query when an item is marked "paid" (for example you could leave the paid indicator to be NULL until it has been paid) and then when this is filled, move it to a separate table, like in version 1.

In other words, all items would be in table 1, until they are paid, when they are automatically moved to table 2 and then deleted from table 1.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE
   ON `UnpaidOrder`.`paid` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

   DECLARE vOrder varchar(50);

   SELECT order_number() INTO vOrder;

   INSERT INTO PaidOrder
   //code here from the first table

   DELETE from `UnpaidOrder`  //if you choose to do so, or you could leave it on the table;  up to you
   //criteria that you wish to delete

END;
```

Comment: Is there much difference between your answer and my first design?

Comment: Oh, now that I look at it closer, I think you are right.  My bad.   Anyway, the tradeoff between the two seems minimal;  the main thing I would be concerned about is looking at the the user-end.  The number wone thing you don't want is to lose customers, so if you have to choose between time between the loading of a cart, and the time between finishing the transaction, I'd choose the latter.  So, this in mind I like your design 1 approach better.

Comment: I think you meant design '2' approach was better in your last sentence (since there's no need to move paid transaction from UnpaidOrder to PaidOrder).

Comment: Actually, design 2 will make it slower for visiting customers, making the cart load slower.   For design 1, the cart is already loaded (it would load faster, right?)   It won't be slow until they have already clicked "purchase."   In other words, they have already have made their decision.   Either way, I don't think you will have too much of a problem (as the other answer suggested, unless you are expecting hundreds of purchases per second :)